# Redirect to external url in play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I was try to redirect to external url by using following code.

routes file contains

```
GET     /move                  controllers.Application.move()
```

Application Class has

```
public static  Result move() {
         return redirect("www.yahoo.com");
}

This tries to call http://localhost:9000/www.yahoo.com instead of redirecting to www.yahoo.com
```

I also tried

```
public static  void move() {
         redirect("www.yahoo.com");
}
```

but code doesn't compile saying

```
 Unspecified value parameter hif.
[error] GET         /move                   controllers.Application.move()
```

Not sure how to redirect to external url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting using the full protocol:

```
redirect("https://www.yahoo.com/")
```

or

```
redirect("http://www.yahoo.com/");
```